# Powershell script check application versions on multiple machines.

Tags: windows, powershell

Im currently running the following commands, but im running them through a foreachloop. I can currently output them both to a csv as just a list for each machine, but ideally id like to output them to a csv of all the machines in the loop, that has the apps listed along the top, then below the computername, version, etc. so that i can append the csv and just have one big csv that i can sort and filter when opened in excel.

Aditionally id also like to be able to alert if app versions are differnt than my baseline, not sure where to start on this though.

```
$InstalledApps = gwmi Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms64 | Select DisplayName, Publisher, Version

$InstalledApps += 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command {gwmi Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms | Select DisplayName, Publisher, Version}

$InstalledApps = $InstalledApps | sort displayname | Get-Unique -AsString

$InstalledApps| Select DisplayName, Publisher, Version | ogv -PassThru | export-csv .\apps.csv
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Powershell v3. and above.

Try to use CimInstance instead of WMI where possible.

```
#Define a Table Array
$MasterTable = @()

#Define computer list
$Computerlist = "computer1", "computer22"

#Run Foreach to retrieve data from each computer remotely
Foreach ($computer in $Computerlist) {
$MasterTable += Get-CimInstance win32_product -Computername $Computer |   
    Select-Object @{Name = "Computername"; Expression = {$Computer}}, 
    @{Name = "SoftwareName"; Expression = {$_.Caption}}, 
    @{Name = "Publisher"; Expression = {$_.Vendor}},
    @{Name = "Version"; Expression = {$_.Version}} 
}

$MasterTable | export-csv .\apps.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

This should give you one CSV export with four columns containing all the information you require (incl the computername Get-CimInstance was run against).

You can do some additional logic with the MasterTable Variable if you like before exporting to CSV

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i try that i get the following : Get-CimInstance : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. A DMTF resource URI was used to access a non-DMTF 
class. Try again using a non-DMTF resource URI.
At line:9 char:17

Comment: @david what is the destination namespace. And the source namespace e.g root\cimv2. You can specify the namespace to query by adding -Namespace “root\xxxx”  to get-ciminstance after -computername $Computer

Comment: They are both on the same domain, having googled i belive its may be due to them not having the latest version of powershell?. Its being run from a 2012 machine against windows 7 machines.

Comment: @david That is correct, CIM doesn't exist in v2, if you can check and make sure that at least v3 is used.

Comment: Damn is there anyway without v3? It would mean rolling out to 600 plus machines.

Comment: Would there be a way to do this using gwmi instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is also possible using WMI, however I would suggest you look at migrating WMI calls to CimInstance instead using Powershell v.3 and above as WMI is legacy and is not really firewall friendly as CimInstance is for example.
But here is the code for using WMI.

```
#Define a Table Array
$MasterTable = @()

#Define computer list
$Computerlist = "computer1", "computer2"

#Run Foreach to retrieve data from each computer remotely
Foreach ($computer in $Computerlist) {
$MasterTable += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computername $Computer |   
    Select-Object @{Name = "Computername"; Expression = {$Computer}}, 
    @{Name = "SoftwareName"; Expression = {$_.Caption}}, 
    @{Name = "Publisher"; Expression = {$_.Vendor}},
    @{Name = "Version"; Expression = {$_.Version}} 
}

$MasterTable | export-csv c:\temp\apps.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```